# How to make a custom element im gst-python

Tags: python, gstreamer

i have quite a lot of experience with python and gst-python, but no experience with plain gstreamer.
does anyone know (well, someone on earth probably does but...) how to create a custom element? i got as far as
`class MyElement(Element):`
by intuition, but i have no idea what next...
simply what i was hoping for was a "*replace this function with the thing you want to happen to every unit that this element is passed*", but i am pretty certain that it will be FAR more complicated than that....

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating a source element, you probably want to subclass `gst.BaseSrc`. Then, IIRC, the main thing you need to do is implement the `do_create()` virtual method. Don't forget to `gobject.type_register()` your class; you may also need to set the time format using `set_format()`.

I second the recommendation to look at the Pitivi source code; it contains several GStreamer elements implemented in Python.